# Добавляет ?i=1 в адресной строке при первом переходе на сайт

Tags: php

На локальном работало все норм, но на хостинге при первом переходе на сайт на любую страницу в адресной строке в конец добавляется ?i=1 в коде нет такой переменной сайт работает с ЧПУ, все запросы через index.php на локалке проблем нет никаких( может это в настройках хостинга, подскажите?

.htaccess

```
php_value display_errors on

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Comment: Или хостинга, или прокси (по типу сервисов антиддос защиты). В любом случае Apache сам по себе ничего не добавляет

Comment: @VladimirGonchar хостинг бесплатный учусь, тестю. В коде ничего не менял и не добавлял после того как перенес на хостинг. тех поддержка только на платном тарифе помогает( спасибо будем искать